# $(p,q)$-forms for analytical spaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $X = X_{\mathbb C}$ be a complex analytical variety. There is a natural functor from complex analytical varities to real analytical varieties
$$
(X, \mathcal{O}_X) \mapsto (X_{\mathbb{R}}, \mathcal{C}^{an}_{X_{\mathbb R}}).
$$
Aware that $X_{\mathbb C}$ and $X_{\mathbb R}$ are in general different topological spaces, though with the same set of points.

For both $X_{\mathbb C}$ and $X_{\mathbb R}$ one can define their Zariski tangent sheaves $\mathcal{T}X_{\mathbb C}$ and $\mathcal{T}X_{\mathbb R}$.

So my questions are the following:

- Is there any way to reconstruct $\mathcal{T}X_{\mathbb C}$ from $\mathcal{T}X_{\mathbb R}$ and vice versa?
- More concretely, for a point $x \in X$ let $\mathcal{T}_xX_{\mathbb C}$ (resp. $\mathcal{T}_xX_{\mathbb R}$) be the fiber of the Zariski tangent sheaf in $x$. Is there a canonical isomorphism $\mathcal{T}_xX_{\mathbb C} \simeq \mathcal{T}_xX_{\mathbb R} \otimes \mathbb{C}$?
- Finally, is there any way to define the sheaf of $(p,q)$-forms $\Omega^{p,q}(X)$ on $X_{\mathbb R}$  which embedds into the sheaf $\Lambda^{p+q}\mathcal{T}^*X_{\mathbb R}$ and coinsides with the sheaf of sections of the bundle of $(p,q)$-forms when $X$ is smooth?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on your natural functor $X\mapsto X_{\mathbb{R}}$ ? I am not even sure what would be $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ if $X$ is for example the line $y=ix$ in $\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$.

Comment: Well, it is a ringed space with the structure sheaf of real analytical functions on this line (which is, if you wish,  a real analytical variety in $\mathbb{R}^4$ given by equations $\operatorname{Re}(x) = \operatorname{Im} (y)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(x) = -\operatorname{Re}(y)$.

It is sufficiently to define this functor on affine analytical varieties and each set of zeros of a holomorphic function $\{f = 0\}$ is clearly an real analytical variety given by equation $\mathrm{Re}(f) = \mathrm{Im}(f) = 0$.

Comment: Ok this is what I thought, but I was surprised by your sentence "Aware that $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ and $X_{\mathbb{R}}$ are in general different topological spaces". As a topological space, this is exactly the same thing, only their ring of function differ, right ?

Comment: @Roland what I meant is that the Zarisski analytic topology on $X_{\mathbb C}$ (on which the sheaf of holomorphic functions is naturally defined) does not coincide with the real analytic Zarisski topology. For example most of the closed analytic subvarieties in $X_{\mathbb R}$ _are_not_ closed in $X_{\mathbb C}$.

I guess that a more delicate way to think about it as  the same set of points endowed with different topologies. The identity map here is not continuous!

Comment: Ok I never used the analytic Zariski topology, I thought you were talking about the usual analytic (euclidian) topology. I will think about your problem then.